# Pre-populate Calendly fields

Tags: forms, calendly

I'm embedding Calendly into Webflow, and everything is working. However, I want to pre-populate the Calendly form, and it's not working. Here's the code I'm using:

```
const params = (new  URL(window.location)).searchParams

Calendly.initInlineWidget({
    url: 'https://calendly.com/mylink/30min',
    prefill: {
        name: params.get('john'),
        email: params.get('john@gmail.com')
    }         
});
```

Comment: Could you provide an example URL that you are using? Looking at your code example, the code assumes that the query param key names would be `john` and `john@gmail.com` (ex: `https://example.com?john=name_value&john@gmail.com=email_address_value`). If the query param keys should be email and name, then you'll want to change the `params` method call to the following: `params.get('name')` and `params.get('email')`

Comment: The problem exists even with these hard coded param names, I'm unable to get the code to work.